# SQL Server 2005 Performance Issues and Testing

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

I have statistical math functions that use intense sql queries and run in an sql assembly.  I just increased the RAM on my db server (IIS 6, SQL Server 2005) but my queries still suck up 100% of my CPU for the 5 minutes I allow for the assemblies to run.  Is there any way to allow the assemblies to cap their CPU? At 100% the server becomes unresponsive. Any sql tuning would help too.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's the new RAM that's causing the issue..? have you ran any type of Profiler or looked at any code that's consuming SQL Functions, StoredProc's or Select Statements..??

Comment: In SQL 2008+ you can use the Resource Governor, but with earlier versions there's no standard way to do that. And even then, it seems that some CLR functions are [not managed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/01/10/sql-server-2008-resource-governor-questions.aspx) by the RG anyway. So the best option is probably to optimize your code, which requires a lot of knowledge about the code and data. Perhaps you can isolate an example of 'problem code' and ask for improvements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLServer 2008 has a resource governor that allows you to throttle the CPU and/or I/O based on the db username that is used for a given connection.  If upgrading to SQL Server 2008 is an option for you, your stats assembly could use a dedicated database username that allows it to consume 100% of the CPU unless another db connection needs CPU, then it yields to the other processes.

This works very well.  We have queries and reports that do complex statistical analysis of thousands of data points.  It too is CPU intensive.  Before we upgraded to SQL Server 2008, we have all sorts of performance issues.  Now everything runs smooth.  The other new features of 2008 are nice, but the resource governor is the real reason we upgraded.

Comment: thanks, but I don't think at this time we are allowed to upgrade yet